# Compare objects which can be null and empty string ("")

Tags: java, object, null, string

Hello I've come to a point where i need a function which compares 2 objects from different sources among other things it also compares strings while form one source iget a null and from the other an empty object string.

my code is

```
private static boolean areDifferent(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if ("".equals(o1)) {
        o1 = null;
    }
    if ("".equals(o2)) {
        o2 = null;
    }
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
        return !(o1 == o2);
    }
    return !o1.equals(o2);
}
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: It seems a bad idea to replace your object from "" to null in a method which isn't supposed to modify anything.

Comment: Good point I should modify that

Comment: it will fail for `areDifferent("", "");` and certain other cases too.

Comment: Your desired result is so to speak _strange_, at least. Treating `null` as empty `String` or empty `String` as `null` will have a side effect: the following will say that an `Integer` number and a `String` are equal (not different): `Integer i = null; boolean diff = areDifferent("",i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a ternary for it (and I would convert null to ""):

```
return !(o1 == null ? "" : o1).equals(o2 == null ? "" : o2);
```

Comment: this will also fail if both objects are "".

Comment: @Batty - the truth-table for the above is the same as the OP's. It will return 'false' if both values are `""`, which is the correct response for a method called `areDifferent`

Comment: yes, i agree, results will be same, but name suggests "" should return true, anyways +1 for putting so many lines of code in a line. :)

Comment: after some testesting it seems all right to me works for every case I need Thanks a lot